# How to change the time format in the chart?

Tags: angular

How can I remove the display of seconds in the chart?I have a chart where the time is displayed in the format `hh.mm.ss`.

Here is the complete code for how the chart is drawn.

ts:

```
 @ViewChild('state') stateRef: ElementRef

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    const densityConfig: any = {
      label: 'Density',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 150, 136, .2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0, 121, 107, .7)',
      borderWidth: 2
    }

    const visconsityConfig: any = {
      label: 'Visconsity',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 137, 132, .2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0, 10, 130, .7)',
      borderWidth: 2
    }

    const stateTimeConfig: any = {
      datasets: [ visconsityConfig, densityConfig]
    }

    this.stateService.fetch().subscribe((data: State[]) => {
      densityConfig.data = data.map(item => item.density)
      visconsityConfig.data = data.map(item => item.visconsity)
      stateTimeConfig.labels = data.map(item => item.state_time)
      const stateCtx = this.stateRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d')

      new Chart(stateCtx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: stateTimeConfig,
        options: {
          responsive: true
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

html:

```
<div *ngIf="states">
  <canvas  #state></canvas>
</div>
```

`state_time` is responsible for the time.

Comment: Look at using the angular DatePipe https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use the built in date Pipe from Angular:

I created a short [StackBlitz to see it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqcyll)

And for brevity made some small changes but you can see the important bits here:

The ts file is simply an array of dates:

```
  labels: Date[] = [new Date('2018/10,5 01:15:31'), 
     new Date('2017/2/25 01:15:10'), new Date('2001/1/1 12:10:01')];
  }
```

and the html file is:

```
<div *ngFor="let date of labels">
  Short Time: {{date | date:'shortTime'}} 
  hhmm: {{date | date:'HH:mm'}} 
</div>
```

More information on available formats for the [Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

---

#### Update

Seeing that this is Angularjs, or at least on the backend I think your best bet is using Javascript:

```
stateTimeConfig.labels = data.map(item => item.state_time.toLocaleTimeString([],
     {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12:false}))
```

Hour is HH, for the 2-digit.
Minute, and hour 12 means for those of us on the strange 12 hour system it will Show 12:15 instead of 12:15 AM/ PM. If you want AM/ PM then just leave that option out.

Comment: I don’t need Html as I have what’s there `<div *ngIf="states">
  <canvas  #state></canvas>
</div>`

Comment: You need the html, as that *is* where the Date Pipe goes. Unless whatever chart you are using can't use it... In which case your question is far from complete.

Comment: This is chart.js for Angular 2+ ?

Comment: Updated. I left the Angular 2+ stuff in case someone is doing something similar with a chart that is out of the box compatible with the date pipe.